# Adding a multiselect to a dropdown menu

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-select

I'm trying to get a multiselect selector from bootstrap-select in my dropdown from bootstrap 4.
But every time I try to open the multiselect my dropdown menu closes and I can't figure out why this happens or how to prevent it.
In the same dropdown menu I have a normal selector and that does the exact same thing.

```
<a data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="#">
    <button style="margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 10px;" class='btn btn-success'>Nieuwe module</button>
</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu" style="margin-top: 25px !important;">
    <div style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;">
        <h5 class="card-title">Nieuwe module toevoegen</h5>
        <form action="modulemanager.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Termijn</label>
                <select name="newtermijn" class="form-control">
                    <option value="0" selected>Eenmalig</option>
                    <option value="1">Per maand</option>
                    <option value="2">Per jaar</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Categorie</label>
                <select name="newcat[]" class="selectpicker" multiple title="Kies categorieën">
                    <option value="0" selected>Eenmalig</option>
                    <option value="1">Per maand</option>
                    <option value="2">Per jaar</option>>
                </select>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-primary">Toevoegen</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25443347/show-bootstrap-select-inside-bootstrap-button-dropdown) solution that made the normal select work but not the bootstrap-select dropdown